# To make entire column names in lower case in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using oracle xe,while creating columns it is created in upper case.Is there any rule to make the entire database columns in lower case.

Comment: embed them in double quotes, in ur DDL, and now it gets case sensitive.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/thread/1069328?tstart=0

Comment: Is there any rule to make the entire database columns in lower case.

Comment: @Saj It doesn't matter. Columns names are not case sensitive. Any reason why you want it in lower case?

Comment: Default is UPPERCASE, as stored in the dictionary views, you can just override it for your ddl using double quotes. I dont think, we can make it lower case by default.. While in querying the actual table, case doesnt matter.

Comment: Unless you have very good reasons, don't do it. Not all tools handle case senistive objects names well. create table emp will allow select * from EMP | Emp | emp. create table "emp" will only allow select * from "emp".

Comment: leave it alone! if you use double quotes you make it case sensitive. The default is uppercase, it's better you get used to that rather than making it case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The double quotes working fine for me.

Answer (score 4):

To answer to your specific question: No
(you cannot globally change all column headings to lowercase)

**Nonquoted Identifiers:**
Unless you use quotes when creating objects the default for storage is upper case and these are called nonquoted identifiers in documentation. This allows "case insensitive" use of those names. e.g. a field stored with the name DESCRIPTION can be used in lowercase or mixed case like dEscRipTion

**Quoted Identifiers**
If however you use "quoted identifiers" then you create **case sensitive** names and all references to them must be a precise match. So a field with the stored name of DesCripTion must always be used with exactly that mixed case and DescripTion would not work.

In short, don't mess with the defaults, you are way better off leaving them as "nonquoted identifiers"

see: [Schema Object Naming Rules](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements008.htm)

Comment: I didn't understand why don't mess with the defaults? I'm designing my db with lowercase letters because my application is multidatabase and works with MsSql too. Will it cause any problem in the future?

Comment: I cannot add much that isn't already in my answer. If you insist on using quoted identifiers you make your solution case sensitive so it is harder to write and maintain queries in Oracle. You may be willing to accept that for other considerations,.

Answer (score 1):

use oracle "rename" syntax.
for example:

```
//  existing column on TABLE1 is CITY_NAME 
// new name is  cityName
// you can rename table and/or columns
rename table SCHEMA1.TABLE1 to "NewTableName"
```

and

```
rename column SCHEMA1.TABLE1.CITY_NAME to "cityName"
```

the main thing to remember is to enclose the new name in quotes.
you have to modify your exiting views and cursors because they will break.